# Deploy a Symfony2 app on cPanel

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel, web-deployment

I'm new to cPanel and I want to deploy my Symfony2 app on it.
I need some guidance on how to do it, 
I downloaded the Symfony2 framework with the Softaculous Apps Installer.

PS : My app is also on BitBucket.

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting or do you have access to the server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off all: CPanel is just a web-shell arround your linux os that makes it easy to maintain your server from distance through a web interface.

Actualy you do not need softaculous because it just installs an empty new symfony project.

There are globally two ways to install your symfony project.

1. Install git and Composer on your server, use git to pull the project from bitbucket and install the the vendors with 'composer install' or 'composer update'.
2. Upload your complete project from your local computer to the server with FTP.

In both ways you still have to install your database and set your configuration.

Comment: I uploaded the project to cPanel usign FTP, how can I access it through url ?

Comment: You have to find out what your documentroot is. Place a simple helloworld html file in the directory and test if it works. If it works than that will be the 'web' directory. Copy the content of your web directory to this directory.
All other directories will come one directory higher or at least outside the documentroot. If necessary change the path structure inside app.php so that it is able to find the other directories

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared online server then just copy the entire symfony project through FTP, set up your database credentials in `parameters.yml`, and manually delete the `prod` directory inside `var` (symfony ≥ 2.8) or `app` (symfony ≤ 2.7).