# Symfony 3 application on a CPANEL won't work

Tags: php, symfony

I have working symfony 3 application on my local computer and I have uploaded the whole application on my **CPANEL** hosting that has no **SSH** access and under root `public_html` (www.domain.com). I just used FTP account to upload directories. I have made no changes before I upload the application to my hosting except I removed the directory `\var\cache` and `\var\logs`.

However, when I try to access the application using the url, all I see are the application directories and application doesn't run.

**UPDATE**

**Step 1. I moved all SF directories in home directory like so,**

home/swipecom

- cache
- **contactless** (Where SF directories live)
- public_html (`/web` the only SF directory)
- var
- ssl
- tmp
- public_ftp
- logs

Step 2. I created an .htaccess in `public_html` like so

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /web/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's the error I encountered.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've changed the path of `public_html/web/app.php` like so, to redirect to `/home2/swipecom/contactless/app/autoload.php`

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */

$loader = require '/home2/swipecom/contactless/app/autoload.php';
include_once '/home2/swipecom/contactless/var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Here's what I encountered

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've googled the problem and I found out that there's an issue with PHP version, that is why I quick to change my PHP version from 5.4 (native) to 5.5 and here I got another problem.

[image]

Comment: Point your host to the `/web` directory.

Comment: I tried to access the web folder using `www.domain.com/web` and here's the result `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/swipecom/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php on line 224`

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451529/deploy-a-symfony2-app-on-cpanel  I think it might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I moved all the sf directories into `home directory` except the `web` directory that I just put into `web root` or `public_html`, now the error I encountered is `require(/home/swipecom/public_html/web/../app/autoload.php): failed to open stream:` maybe I have to change the directory of inside of app.php right? But how do I redirect the path into `home directory`?

Answer (score 0):

The `web` folder should be your web root.

Also you will need to keep your `var\cache` and `var\logs` folders. They are there for a reason.

Comment: You mean I must copy all the files inside of /web folder and paste to www.domain.com?

Comment: No, you have to keep the standard Symfony directory structure. Just specify the web folder as the web root. not sure how that is done in cpanel.

Comment: I update my code above, can you check If this is correct. thanks